# Why are my related products not displaying on my product page?

Tags: magento

I have gone to admin -> manage product -> product information page -> related products

Then I added a product that is related, and saved.

I went to that product and refreshed the page, but nothing changed. Why not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic since it is about Magento in general, not programming/writing code for Magento. General Magento questions can be asked on https://magento.stackexchange.com, instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Solution**:

- Login to Admin
- Go to **System -> Index Management**
- Select All checkboxes
- Select '**Reindex Data**' from Actions selection list
- Click Submit button

Reference: [Magento Up-sells Cross-sells and Related products are not showing up](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-up-sells-cross-sells-and-related-products-are-not-showing-up/)

Answer (score 23):

Also, be sure to check that the product you're trying to see in 'Related Products' is not already in your cart. Magento has a default filter applied that removes items in the cart from the related products collection.

Comment: ALSO make sure it's selected on the correct website (if your site uses multiple websites and has that attribute). If none are selected, it won't show up on any of them.

Answer (score 6):

- Related Products appear in product info page, in the right column.
- Cross Sell items appear in the shopping cart.
- Upsells for this product are items that your customers would ideally buy instead of the product they’re viewing.These appear on the product info page underneath the product description.

As a result, I understand that you would show products bottom of the product info page, you should choose upsells instead of related products.

If you want related products ( which I can misunderstanding you ) do following things :

- Check related product status is enabled.
- Check visibility status set "Catalog" or "Catalog Search"
- If everything is fine, check the inventory of related products.Stock should be greater than 0.
- Last thing, related products must be include a category. Click "categories" link to check and see if the product added in a category.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the "Reset Filter" button on top of the related product listing. It will list all products in table. Or you can clear cache + reindex data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After some time ago, I found that the products are not made to be visible in the visibility section, and that the products are not set to be in any website.

Hope this is the answer, and should be, because if you set up everything right there is nothing that can make problems.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the product and related product are under the same website. This isn't apparent when adding the relating products.

Answer (score 1):

One possible pitfall you can run into is that you use a template without a right column. In that case you have to use unsetChild and insert to move the related product block.

Comment: Can you elaborate? what is unsetChild how do i use it. where do i insert what to?

Comment: `unsetChild` and `insert` are actions that you can apply in your layout XML to move blocks from one structural block to another. `<action method="unsetChild">` and `<action method="insert">`. Related Question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143419/moving-a-block-to-a-different-block